# How to keep on top of past posts for referencing

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

When I joined I initially read many posts but didn't pay much attention to where they were for future reference, barring a passing nod to their respective tags. There was one integration question I now want to link to in one of my questions but I can't find it. How do other people successfully navigate the site? I noticed the star button on the question for favourites, is this akin to a bookmarking system? Is it best to keep a note of the numbers of any questions you like in case you need to reference them, or can this be automated in some way? I guess I'm just asking for general advice as to how others manage their accounts as everything in the site is well laid out, but a bit overwhelming in size (but isn't everything). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, favorites are bookmarks. It's favorites as in Internet Explorer for example. (Not favorite like in "my favorite questions," though there could be some correlation.) You can access them in your user profile and when you visit them those that changed are higlighted;

Comment: @quid. Great, thanks. This answers a question I had about down votes: if I down voted someone I could favourite that question and then if the answer changed I would see this in my user profile and could get rid of the down vote if the answer had improved.

Comment: Yes, this is a potential use case. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work for details on how they work. Note though that your favorites are public.

Comment: Since you asked about searching too, I will mention [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21900/how-to-search-math-terms-notations-accurately-and-efficiently-could-some-experi) and [several other similar question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/links-about-searching-for-posts-on-mse). Maybe you can find more simply by looking among posts tagged ([meta-tag:search]) here on meta.